# Before Authentification in Laravel

Tags: laravel, web, service, authentication, laravel-artisan

I use Laravel authentification by Artisan,
I want to Login with email/password but before that i want to call a web service,so the result of web service return true the login continue, but if return false it redirect in login page with error message.
How to do it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. Please paste here the code you have right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware) (example in the documentation will give you a better understanding) for that. Write a middleware calling your web service as bellow inside app/http/middleware,

you can define a middleware using the artisan command; `php artisan make:middleware Webservice`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class WebserviceMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {   
        // get return value of the web service
        $return_value = webservice.call();

        if (!$return_value)
        {
            //if return value is false define the redirect to login route
            return redirect('/');
        }

        //else let the request to be proceeded.
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And register the middleware by icluding it inside the $routemiMiddleware property of as follow;

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        //other exisiting middleware
        'webservice' =>  \App\Http\Middleware\WebserviceMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

Now put the auth routes by laravel default authentication inside the middlware inside the web.php as follow,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'webservice'], function () {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

or by,

```
Auth::routes()->middleware('webservice');
```

Now the webservice return value is evaluated before proceeding.